# Prevent selenium grid from randomly closing remote sessions

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm running into a problem where Selenium Grid randomly closes the session running on my test machine. Sounds like a lot like the following reported issue:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4156

This primarily happens during my testing so if my test fails for whatever reason and it doesn't get to the method where I close the session i.e "driver.close()" the session will continue to run. If I need to fix something and restart my test the session starts up normally but the Grid will randomly close the session and I see the following message in the node console:

```
Executing: [delete session: .... ] at URL: /sesssion/....
```

It's really annoying to say the least, does anyone know of a way to close the session completely without having to restart the node or grid?

Comment: I think the code to close the session must be 'driver.quit'. driver.close() just closes the current instance of browser window.

Comment: @Harsha you cannot use driver.quit() because it will close all the open driver instance on the slave, i.e if there are tests running parallely on your slave machine then all of a sudden it will close all the open browser instances.

Comment: @so cal cheesehead : you need to increase the browserTimeout and sessionTimeout parameter.